# How to prevent integer from being treated as string

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$number = 1;

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $pageID = $row[0];
    $pageName = $row[1];
    $timeStamp = $row[5];

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                $number;
                $number++;
            </td>
            <td><a href=\"./lib/viewpage.php?pageID=$pageID\" target=\"_blank\">$pageName</a></td>
            <td>$timeStamp</td>
        </tr>";
    }
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to have that to have the number increase by 1 for every row and I found the above solution that uses the "$integer++" method. However, since I have it in quotations, it is instead treated as a string instead of a decimal. How would you correct this?

I am new to PHP!

Comment: I'd increment after the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the the addition operator outside of the quotations and only include the set variable. This means that you'll have to set "$number = 0;"

like so:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $pageID = $row[0];
    $pageName = $row[1];
    $timeStamp = $row[5];

    $number;
    $number++;

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                $number
            </td>
            <td><a href=\"./lib/viewpage.php?pageID=$pageID\" target=\"_blank\">$pageName</a></td>
            <td>$timeStamp</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to Rahul Mankar's answer
replace that section with

```
<td>".($number++)."</td>
```

`$number++` will echo the value of number first then add 1 to it.
BTW : While this will fix it, I don't recommend putting an incrementer in the middle of an echo

Answer (score 0):

In your code, $number is treating as a string because it is in the echo statement. And whole echo statement has a double quoted string. Just concat the string with number.  So write like wise:

```
$number = 1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $pageID = $row[0];
    $pageName = $row[1];
    $timeStamp = $row[5];
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>".
                $number;
                $number++;
            ."</td>
            <td><a href=\"./lib/viewpage.php?pageID=$pageID\" target=\"_blank\">$pageName</a></td>
            <td>$timeStamp</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

Comment: That would cause the number to appear twice you know.